# how to throw an exception using Assert.Throws in Xunit

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

i am trying to write a test case using Xunit where i want check if the text i am passing is not expected one throw exception saying the value should be the same only

Here is my code

```
   [Theory]
   [InlineData("Goods","Goods")]
   [InlineData("Test","Goods")]
   public void Vehicle(string use,string expected)
   {
      // Arrange
      var risk= CreateRisk();
      var request = new Request();

      risk.Use = use;
      
      // Act
      Test().Mapping(risk, request);
      
      // Assert
     Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(expected != "Goods" ? "Vehicle Use Should be with Goods": expected);
  
   }
```

I am not sure how i can frame this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to throw an exception? What is wrong with a simple `Assert.Equal(expected, "whatever")`?

Comment: @DavidG actully the file from which i am mapping the data to my class contains text other than "Goods" but i expect only "Goods" and if any text other than this then want to throw exception

Comment: `Assert.Throws` asserts that the method passed as an argument throws the specified exception. Use `Assert.Equal` to ensure a result matches the expected value. Use `Assert.All` to ensure all items in a collection match other assertions, eg `Assert.All(items,it=>Assert.Equal("Goods",it.Name))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to capture the exception result during your act:

```
  // Act
  var result = Assert.Throws<ArgumentException(() => Test().Mapping(risk, request));
  
  // Assert
 result.Message.Should().Be(expected);
```